# Kind of mutable image in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, mutable

I am searching for a image class which is mutable. 
As you know NSArray is not mutable and NSMutableArray is mutable.

Apple Documentation about UIImage

> Image objects are immutable, so you cannot change their properties
>   after creation.

What I want is to change the color of an image after creation.
How is it possible?

Comment: What exactly to you mean by "changing the color" of an image? Do you want to apply a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Core Image to tap into the image's bitmap and apply a filter and then render a new image.

More specifically, you can create a custom subclass of `CIFilter` to apply a custom filter to your image and render it.

Unfortunately, there are many things that you'll need to do to accomplish this, including having to write some kernel code & testing it in QC, declaring a new interface, writing a couple of methods, registering and finally creating a factory method. It's a lot of stuff, but, well, it is what it is.

See the [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH207-TPXREF101) and the [Core Image Filters Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).